# Mathematica интегралы

Tags: анализ, mathematica

Как подобрать замену, приводящую интеграл от заданной функции к интегралу от рациональной функции и разложить на простые дроби методом неопределенных коэффициентов  c помощью wolfram mathematica?

Answer (score 0):

можно попробовать так:

```
f[x_]=... - изначальная функция

F[x_] = FunctionInterpolation[f[x],{x, x0, x1}]

Integrate[F[x],x]
```